# Ubuntu didn't install boot menu!

Tags: boot, grub2, menu

I installed Ubuntu on a netbook from a usb flash drive but after the restart there is no grub menu and just Windows starts. How to add the boot menu for ubuntu? The netbook doesn't have a cd but I can run Hiren's boot from the usb drive.
I usually use EasyBCD for such problems but it gives errors that it cannot find any boot record/mbr on the disk and doesn't allow me to do anything...

I don't recall the model but the solution I chose fixed my problem immediately :). The only drawback is the ubuntu menu waits for around 10 seconds to load ubuntu if the user doesn't push enter.

Comment: What kind of netbook is this? Does it run uefi? What version of Windows is installed? Do you have fast-boot disabled? Please click "Edit" below your question and add the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think that this might be an issue with MBR and in order to recover grub follow the steps and check whether it fixes your issue.

```
1. Pop in the Live CD, boot from it until you reach the desktop.
2. Open a terminal window or switch to a tty.
3. Type "grub"
4. Type "root (hd0,6)", or whatever your harddisk + boot partition numbers are (my /boot is at /dev/sda7, which translates to hd0,6 for grub).
5. Type "setup (hd0)", ot whatever your harddisk nr is.
6. Quit grub by typing "quit".
7. Reboot.
```